# Using .addClass after 0 seconds, rather than 10, if HTML element doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery to display 1 message at a time, from up to 3 possible messages, every 10 seconds:

HTML:

```
            <div class="mszDivOuter">
              <div class="mszDiv activeMsz">message 1</div>
              <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 2</div>
              <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 3</div>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){ 
            jQuery(".mszDivOuter").each(function(){
                var cnt = crActiveMsz = nextMszNum = 0; 
                cnt = $(this).children('.mszDiv').length;
                if(cnt > 1){
                    crActiveMsz = $(this).children('.activeMsz').index();
                    nextMszNum = crActiveMsz + 2;

                    if(nextMszNum > cnt){ nextMszNum = 1;}

                    $(this).children('.mszDiv').removeClass("activeMsz");
                    $(this).children('.mszDiv').addClass("deactiveMsz");

                    $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').removeClass("deactiveMsz");
                    $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').addClass("activeMsz");
                }
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
```

However, sometimes I don't want to use a particular messages, for example, with PHP I can condition message 1 to not show up at all, like this:

HTML:

```
            <div class="mszDivOuter">
            <?php if ($condition==true) { ?>
              <div class="mszDiv activeMsz">message 1</div>
            <?php } else { } ?> 
              <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 2</div>
              <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 3</div>
            </div>
```

But in this case, when the page loads, the message DIV will remain blank for the first 10 seconds, and only then will start toggling between message 2 and 3.

Is there a smart, universal way, to avoid this waiting period, and display message 2 right away? (or message 3, in case I will disable message 2 with PHP as well).

CSS:

```
.mszDiv{ position:absolute; transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); -0-transform: translateY(-50%); top:50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); top:50%;}
 .activeMsz{ opacity:1;
 -webkit-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -moz-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -o-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -ms-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
 }
 .deactiveMsz{ opacity:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the anonymous function out of setInterval and name it:

```
function switchMsg() {
    jQuery(".mszDivOuter").each(function(){
        var cnt = crActiveMsz = nextMszNum = 0; 
        cnt = $(this).children('.mszDiv').length;
        if(cnt > 1){
            crActiveMsz = $(this).children('.activeMsz').index();
            nextMszNum = crActiveMsz + 2;

            if(nextMszNum > cnt){ nextMszNum = 1;}

            $(this).children('.mszDiv').removeClass("activeMsz");
            $(this).children('.mszDiv').addClass("deactiveMsz");

            $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').removeClass("deactiveMsz");
            $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').addClass("activeMsz");
        }
    });
}
```

Within document ready, call that function, then set up the interval:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  switchMsg();
  setInterval(switchMsg, 10000);
});
```

Comment: thanks. In my scenario, I might have on same page, the same HTML block, several times, for example, in case in first block, I will have only the last 2 messages, and on second block I'll have all 3, I see that with your code, message 2 will be the first to show also for the second HTML block. any way to make message 1 to show first, for that block?